# Add icon to end of radio input div

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm attempting to create a similar UI as below using radio inputs. Most of the UI was fairly easy to recreate, the only exception is adding the arrow (icon?) to the end of the label div. I've attempted to div an arrow in and force it to the center using margins, but it's obviously not a very good solution. What's the best way to add the arrow at the end of the label?

Here's the current code

```
<div id='results'>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="result" value="1" id='opt-1' checked>
   <label for="opt-1"><h3>Option 1</h3>
   <p>Short Description of Option 1</p></label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="result" value="2" id='opt-2' checked>
   <label for="opt-2"><h3>Option 2</h3>
   <p>Short Description of Option 2</p></label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="result" value="3" id='opt-3' checked>
   <label for="opt-3"><h3>Option 3</h3>
   <p>Short Description of Option 3</p></label><br>
</form> 
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmsme8Lp/#&togetherjs=hVTmifCmM9)

[image: End Product]

EDIT:

I'm aware the JSFiddle doesn't apply the background correctly. The code does operate fine on production.
[image]

Comment: Add your css also, what you have tried

Comment: _"What's the best way to add the arrow at the end of the label?"_ - an absolutely positioned pseudo-element. (Add padding on the right, if you need to prevent it from overlapping the text, which will then break into a second row if necessary ... if that situation will even ever occur with such a navigation.)

Comment: Couple of questions: The fiddle doesn't look remotely like the target. Are you planning on updating it until it starts to resemble it? And, if you are providing a list of options where only one can be picked at a time, then why are you bothering with the arrow at all? How would an arrow work with this type of layout?

Comment: You should get rid of the form and make a list. Unless you are trying to do something else.

Comment: @flyer dev site has a lot of built in css that makes everything operate correctly. For some reason, the fiddle isn't filling the background on the label divs, but it does operate correctly in production.

Comment: @NikosGatzoulis I only went with a radio input because I'm pretty familiar with the jquery methods to retrieve the selected value, how would switching to a list simplify the process? I'm open to that.

Comment: @CBroe will a pseudo element continue the gradient background div without and obvious visual break? I did look at that route but was unsure if the background-color would translate well.

Comment: Since the pseudo element is absolutely positioned, it is laying on top of the gradient ...

Comment: If this was some sort of navigation (as I also assumed, based on the first image shown only at the time), a list of links would be best practice; but since you seem to rather want the user to choose an option here, radio buttons are the way to go. Whether a form around them is actually needed, depends on whether you want to be able to submit the selected option to the server as a non-JS fallback, or if client-side script access to the selected option is the only requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a wrapper of class **.list** for each radio item to bind the data.

```
 <div id='results'>
  <form>
   <div class="list">   
   <span>
        <input  type="radio" name="result" value="1" id='opt-1' checked>
   </span>
   <span class="radio-content">
      <span>
        <label class="mb-1" for="opt-1"><h3>Option 1</h3>
        <p class="d-inline">Short Description of Option 1</p></label><br>
      </span>
     <span class="arrow"><</span>
   </span>
  </div>
   <div class="list">   
   <span>
        <input  type="radio" name="result" value="1" id='opt-1' checked>
   </span>
   <span class="radio-content">
      <span>
        <label class="mb-1" for="opt-1"><h3>Option2</h3>
        <p class="d-inline">Short Description of Option 2</p></label><br>
      </span>
     <span class="arrow"><</span>
   </span>
 </div>
</form> 
</div>
```

CSS code here

```
.list{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.mb-1{
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.radio-content{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: This is *EXACTLY* what I was looking for. Thank you for the thorough response!

Comment: Always welcome :) JUst change the class names.... I give some stupid class names :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "<" you can use the appropriate icon with the appropriate spacing

```css
label {
  background-color: #16a085;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #16a085, #66a99c);
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

form > label > h3 {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

form > label > p {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

form > label h3::after {
  content: '\276E';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='results'>
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="result" value="1" id='opt-1' checked>
    <label for="opt-1">
      <h3>Option 1</h3>
      <p>Short Description of Option 1</p>
    </label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="result" value="2" id='opt-2' checked>
    <label for="opt-2">
      <h3>Option 2</h3>
      <p>Short Description of Option 2</p>
    </label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="result" value="3" id='opt-3' checked>
    <label for="opt-3">
      <h3>Option 3</h3>
      <p>Short Description of Option 3</p>
    </label><br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I prefer this one over the flexbox-is-awesome ;-) answers, because no-nonsense HTML is even more awesome, and since that arrow seems to be purely decorative, it belongs into the CSS rather than as an extra element into the HTML. And unless there is an explicit requirement to be able to change the label background based on the radio button state, I would even put the input inside the label - saves the hassle of keeping id- and for-attributes matching (the for attribute can be removed without replacement) and unique (think of that same component being used more than once on a page maybe.)

Comment: And speaking of no-nonsense HTML, we should probably go for _valid_ HTML first of all. `h3` and `p` can not be put inside a `label` (not your mistake, came from the original example), because that allows [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) inside only. So I'd go with `strong` for the option "headline" and an additional `span` for the description - the latter only if additional formatting control over the description is needed.

Comment: Yo @CBroe -- thank you for being one of those fantastic people that goes beyond narrow answers but rather opts to share helpful and expansive knowledge on the overall project. That's what makes community based knowledge sharing work. All of this is REALLY helpful!

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for the full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

So **flexbox** is awesome for layouts like these. It performs well and has great browser support (http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). IE has some issues but should be able to work around.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.title h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.title p {
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #aaa;
  margin: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle-switch {
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="icon">*</span>
    <div class="title">
      <h3>Stops</h3>
      <p>Non stop, 1 stop, 2+ stops</p>
    </div>
    <span class="toggle-switch">^</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="icon">*</span>
    <div class="title">
      <h3>Duration</h3>
      <p>Any</p>
    </div>
    <span class="toggle-switch">^</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```